# Calculating in MySQL with variables results in conversion from decimal to double. Why?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This simple query

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `a` decimal(27,9) NOT NULL,
  `b` decimal(27,9) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO `test` SELECT '0.1', '0.2';
COMMIT;
SELECT
    @a:=`a` AS `a`,
    `b`,
    `a` + `b` AS `sum1`,
    @a + `b` AS `sum2`,
    CAST(@a AS DECIMAL(27,9)) + `b` AS `sum3`
FROM `test`
```

results in

| a | b | sum1 | sum2 | sum3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.100000000 | 0.200000000 | 0.300000000 | 0.30000000000000004 | 0.300000000 |

- Why did the variable convert to double?
- Does casting the variable as in sum3 prevent a loss of precision here?

In my use case I need to store a quite complex calculation in a variable, do further operations on it and store the result in a new column. To prevent redundancy and not reduce the performance, I would like to do the maths just one and store the result in a variable.

https://dbfiddle.uk/S3dweIzO

Comment: _If the value of a user variable is selected in a result set, it is returned to the client as a string._ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: _In my use case I need to store a quite complex calculation in a variable_... is it something that cannot be done with running sum (analytic functions) or recursive CTE?

Comment: I'm not grouping anything. I have a lot COALESCEs and arithmetic operations on theses. In your linked document this statement concerns me most: _Assignment of decimal and real values does not preserve the precision or scale of the value._ Cannot find more information on this, but it seems it is not safe to use variables in combination with decimals if you want to keep the precision.

Comment: Please explain the need for `decimal(27,9)` and why `DOUBLE` is not suitable for those columns.  `DECIMAL` has certain purposes, I would like to understand whether you are using (versus abusing) them in this situation.

Comment: Also, be aware that `SELECT @a:=...` is deprecated and will be removed in some future version.  Please elaborate on why you are using @variables.

Comment: "Does casting the variable as in sum3 prevent a loss of precision here?" -- Possibly.  Conversion to `DOUBLE` rounds to 53 significant bits (about 16 decimal digits).  You seem to want 27 significant digits in some situations.

Comment: The 27,9 is just for this example. I'm using decimals in a warehousing management application. I need to have accurate mass and pricing values.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a XY problem. You want to:

> Buffer a calculation and calculate further with the variable to not do
> the same calculation multiple times.

[MySQL user varialbes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) are not a solution, one of the reasons being:

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is
> undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1
> evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.

To define an expression once and use it multiple times or in multiple clauses I would suggest using a sub query:

```
select a, b, expr1, a + expr1
from (
    select a, b, a * 0.1 as expr1
    from t
) as x
```

or a lateral join (easier to read compared to sub-queries):

```
select a, b, expr1, expr2, expr1 + expr2
from t,
lateral (select a * 0.1 as expr1) as x,
lateral (select a + expr1 as expr2) as y
```

Comment: This actually works better, but I get too many decimals: `0.300000000000000000000000000000`. Still not quite the result I expect. What's the difference in assigning via SET and inside the SELECT?

Comment: It is decimal(65, 30). Using user variables like the way you did have too many gotchas and at least three of them are involved in your very simple query. I'd suggest using window functions (if it is just a simple running sum) or recursive cte (if it is something like excel formulas referencing columns from previous rows).

Comment: That would imply that I should not assign _and_ use a variable within the same row? Because that is what I'm trying to do. Buffer a calculation and calculate further with the variable to not do the same calculation multiple times.

Comment: exactly. If the idea is to write dont-repeat-yourself code you can use sub queries  or lateral joins (lateral join example https://dbfiddle.uk/SPwEhw1S)

Comment: thanks, that was a great advice. did not know about lateral joins. i replaced all variables with two lateral tables and it seems to work so far.